# c# generate classes and persist them

Tags: c#

I am trying to see if something is possible in c# vs 13 but before i start it i thought i would take experts advise if it's an actual thing in the first place. basically what i want to do is create a solution that would after compiling (in non debug mode i guess) would, given the connection string (threw a basic ui, textbox, web or winforms), connect to db, generate classes based on that connection string and persist them. I am pretty sure this is possible as if i see `Toad` it looks like it works that way.

**Edit** 
To clear what i am asking consider a web page that pops. with a textbox saying "insert database connection string here" and after that you generate the classes inside a folder let's say and tada new c# classes ready to use.

Comment: By "generate a class" do you mean create a new table, which can be loaded/saved into s c# class via an orm?

Comment: i mean as the you compile the project a window pops and says "hey give me the connection string to your db" then that would generate the classes with their props. basically EF without the hole manually thing.

Comment: This is far too broad for SO which is designed for specific programming-issues not for implementations of complex apps and patterns. However there are many tools around for converting DDL to .NET-classes, as already proposed by user1653400

Comment: alright thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are describing Entity Framework Database First.

Yes, it is possible. Unless i am not understanding your question correctly.